# How to rewrite a url with id and title passed

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Basically, what i want is this:

For example, I have a url that looks like this :

**example.com/stories/show.php?id=$id**

I want that url to look like this

**example.com/stories/$id/$title**

And I want the title to look like this:

**I love stackoverflow** to

**I-love-stackoverflow**

Seperating each words with a dash.

Am I supposed to pass the title along with the id??

e.g **example.com/stories/show.php?id=$id&title=$title**

And how do I achieve all this with .htaccess ??

A good example of what I want to do is used by stackoverflow.. Check the url of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need some simple rule like in the below example

```
RewriteEngine on
# rewrite stories/<id>/<title> to show.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} stories/([0-9]+)/([a-z\-A-Z]+)
RewriteRule (.*) show.php?id=%1&title=%2 [L]
```

Place the above in your `.htaccess` file, which should be located under the `stories` folder. Of course you also need to make sure so that the `rewrite` module is enabled on your server. This could be done by running the following commands from the terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo apachectl restart
```

Now you should be able to rewrite an url like:

```
http://example.com/stories/666/stack-overflow
```

to:

```
http://example.com/stories/show.php?id=666&title=stack-overflow
```

Then you could create your links in the following manner:

```
<?php
// php example
$title = "I love stackoverflow";
$id = 666;
?>
<a href="http://example.com/stories/<?php print $id . '/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $title); ?>">link</a>
```

I think you should read up on how url rewriting really works, here is a couple of links that might be useful:

[URL Rewriting for Beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)
[URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Comment: Thank you.. How do I get the title to be seperated with a dash "-"..After each word

Comment: @Ibrahim - Like I said I think you should readup on the basics of url rewriting. You **don't** automatically get dashes through rewriting. You need to create a nice looking url that in turn will get rewritten to your `show.php` file, not the other way around. Follow the above links which will explain this much better than me =)

Comment: I read.. But still cant do this thing. I tried what you gave me and The url became http://example.com/stories/666/i%20love%20stack%20overflow.   The dash(-) I wanted was replaced with percentage (%)...And it didnt read my css again..     Sorry but Am kinda confused..

Comment: @Ibrahim - You're not understanding how url rewriting works. The url will not be changed, you supply the url as `http://example.com/666/i-love-stackoverflow` and this request will be sent to `show.php?id=666&title=i-love-stackoverflow`

Comment: am so sorry, I feel so stupid.   Let's say i have these $id="666"; and  $title="i love my food";  I supplied the url as http://example.com/stories/$id/$title. The result came out as http://example.com/stories/666/i love food   And when I click on the link it  points to the rewrite rule you gave but replaces the space in "i love food" with %....How do i supply the title as i-love-food instead of i love food.   I am so sorry.

Comment: @Ibrahim - This depends entirely of where your data comes from. Does it comes from a database? Are you generating your links dynamically? Then you'll need to create each link so they match the rewrite rule itself. For instance using php you would do something like `<a href="http://example.com/stories/<?php print $id . '/' . str_replace(' ', '-', $title); ?>">link</a>`

Comment: it comes from a database and I dont store titles with dash after each word e.g I-love-food.. I store the titles like I love food... Thats the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot. Now I understand perfectly.